# CalendarView in JavaFX 8

Tags: javafx-8

I am looking for a CalendarView control in JavaFX 8. Is there any built-in control like that or to use the popup calendar from DatePicker control.
My idea is to display a calendar for the user to choose a date from.

Comment: That's what the date picker does.  What do you want different?  [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20369963/2855515)

Comment: What DatePicker does is picks up a selected date from a popup and populates a textfield. What I need is a Calendar shown. Something similar to the calendar displayed in MS Outlook calendar.
For now I am using CalendarView from ExtFX library. Take a look and you will know what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented some controls using the new Data and Time API.

The library is Open Source.

You can read more about it here:

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2013/12/drombler-commons-date-and-time-controls.html

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2013/04/drombler-commons-javafx-controls-for.html

The library is available from Maven Central (requires Java SE 8):

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>  
    <artifactId>drombler-commons-fx-time</artifactId>  
    <version>0.2</version>  
</dependency>
```

If you find some bugs or have some enhancement requests, you can file them here: http://issues.drombler.org/

Comment: I have a question. How to support other languages in the MonthOfYearComboBox?

Comment: All the localized data is provided by the Date and Time API (new in Java 8).

Comment: Note that some names and packages have been renamed to match the names and packages in Java 8. Eg. the class MonthOfYoearComboBox has been renamed to MonthComboBox since the enum has been renamed from MonthOfYear to Month: http://drombler.sourceforge.net/DromblerCommons/docs/site/0.2/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/fx/scene/control/time/MonthComboBox.html

Comment: Puce Thanks. Looks like I can use this library. Do you provide a jar file to directly add to the projects ?