# Listener on some elements

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, listener

A pretty easy question : I have 3 `spinners` and a `DatePicker` in my `Pane` to have a complete `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` date (if there is a better solution than these 4 elements tell me)

And as we can do `find_pseudo.textProperty().addListener(...)` on a `TextField` I want to have a listener on the FOUR element, if one of the 4 has got changes -> hop i can do what I need to (it's set a predicate on a sorted list)

Comment: What code have you tried - can you provide your sample and what you are attempting?

Comment: Add a `InvalidationListener` to all of them...

Comment: Tangentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613619/how-to-make-a-timespinner-in-javafx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
ObjectBinding<LocalDateTime> dateTime = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
    LocalDateTime.of(
        datePicker.getValue(), 
        LocalTime.of(hourSpinner.getValue(), minuteSpinner.getValue(), secondsSpinner.getValue())),
    datePicker.valueProperty(), hourSpinner.valueProperty(), minuteSpinner.valuePropertY(), secondsSpinner.valueProperty());
```

Then `dateTime.getValue()` will be updated when any of the fields are updated, and is also observable, i.e. you can do

```
dateTime.addListener((obs, oldDateTime, newDateTime) -> {
    // do something with newDateTime
});
```

or

```
filteredList.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
    myObject -> myObject.getSomeDateTimeValue().isAfter(dateTime.getValue()),
    dateTime));
```